# Uploading images to MySQL (blob) with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image, pdo, blob

For security reasons I've decided that uploading user profile images to a database, rather than just a folder and uploading the image addresses, would be a good idea.

I've never dealt with file uploads in a backend before, but having read up about this from various sources, I believe that I'm doing everything correctly. However no useful binary data is being uploaded.

in php.ini

> file_uploads=On

In the frontend

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" autocomplete="on" action="upload/">       
    <p>
        <input type="file" id="avatar" name="avatar" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" required />
        <label for="avatar">*Profile photo</label>

    </p>

    <p class="submitter two-thirds columns">
        <input type="submit" value="Apply" />
    </p>
     
</form>
```

In the backend

```
if(isset($_SESSION['id']))
    $UserID = $_SESSION['id'];
else exit(1);

if (!empty($_FILES['avatar'])){
    $photo = fopen($_FILES['avatar']["tmp_name"], 'rb');
    $photo_mime = $_FILES['avatar']["type"]; 
}
else exit(1);

$values_data = array(
    $UserID,
    $photo,
    $photo_mime,
);


$sql = "INSERT INTO `user`
    (
        UserID,
        photo,
        photo_mime
    )
    VALUES
    (
        :UserID,
        :photo,
        :photo_mime
    )
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        photo = :photo,
        photo_mime = :photo_mime
    ";

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);


$sth->bindValue(':UserID', $values_data[0]);
$sth->bindValue(':photo', $values_data[1]);
$sth->bindValue(':photo_mime', $values_data[2]);
$sth->execute();
```

And the database does get *some* information

[image: mysql phpmyadmin]

However those image binaries are all 1KB. Looking inside them they have data that is like this

> Resource id #13

So the binaries are getting messed up or dropped somewhere along the line... but where?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what security issues are storing the images in a db solving?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson my first go-to would be a public folder with address of the images. Even if I stop this folder being navigable or indexable, it would be possible to easily browse user photos by maniplating the URL, unless I had all the image names have large number of random characters... and I'm not sure how secure that would be tbh

Comment: You could keep the images outside of the document root and have a PHP file that acts as a proxy: `image.php?name=foo.jpg` and let the `image.php` file read and output the image data from the image folder. Then you can also add checks to see if a user is logged in or not before outputting the image. It will be just like your db solution, but without needing to store _files_ in the database instead of in the _file_ system (where they belong)..

Comment: @MagnusEriksson oh okay. file_get_contents looks a bit more hopeful. var_dump outputs a massive about of apparently random unicode for that, so that looks right. Uploading to db fails for that though, will check soon

Comment: Let me know if the answer below helped. If yes, feel free to accept it to make other users know it's resolved.

Comment: And how you are going to show these files stored in the database?

Comment: @YourCommonSense I was planning to decode them in a backend script in a user's sort-of profile page

Comment: Decode in response to which request? What event would cause your script to decode the image?

Comment: So you want the images only viewable to registered users?

Comment: @YourCommonSense pretty much. It's not the most sensitive information ever, but it's important that their data has at least a basic level of security attached to it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fopen()` doesn't return the contents of the file. It returns a  file pointer resource, which you then can pass to something like [fread()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php) to get the contents.

Something like:

```
$handler = fopen($_FILES['avatar']["tmp_name"], 'r');
$file = fread($handler, filesize($_FILES['avatar']["tmp_name"]));
fclose($handler);
```

An easier way would be to use [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php):

```
$file = file_get_contents($_FILES['avatar']["tmp_name"]);
```

which will give you the contents in one line.

Comment: This solved the immediate issue. I believe that the connection to the database takes too long though (Mysql Server has gone away error) so I think that I will implement your "below the document root" suggestion

Comment: Just to be 100% clear: It's not "below" the document root (which could be interpreted as under/inside), it should be "outside" (like above/beside) of the document root (to prevent direct access from clients). But yes, that would probably be a better choice.

Comment: I think given the context it was clear that we weren't talking about a www/public_html/img type of path

Comment: It's still always good to be 100% clear. Sometimes you might think something is obvious while others don't :-) It's also to clarify it for any future visitors. I've learned to assume as little as possible.